# Fabric CA Server DB in the Client

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am building a Hyperledger Fabric blockchain application (docker containers) where I have created also an application gateway (docker container) with node js to interact with it as a backend service.

For my surprise I have witnessed the following case:
I have registered new users and enrolled them through the application gateway and the official Fabric SDK using the CAs of the network and stored them in the Fabric Wallet. And I realized that they are stored in a different fabric-ca-server.db than the one that lives under the /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/ directory of the fabric ca docker container.

What I mean is that when I tried to list the identities through the cli I got zero identities since they were registered through SDK. And when I tried to register the same identities from the SDK I got the usual message of user is already registered.

But I was not able to find where this fabric-ca-server.db is stored that reads for the application gateway (SDK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DB file can be found in the CA container using the following path

```
/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
```

You will find that this path is also mentioned in the docker compose file.

Comment: Yes that was my first impression too. To look under the ca container. I forgot to mention that. I have searched in this db also but same result. The users of the sdk are not stored there but only users registered from the cli. And that was really strange for me!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is the correct path!!

Answer (score 0):

The correct path as is stated in the above answer is the directory inside the fabric CA container!

My mistake was that through the application SDK I was only enrolling some admins without registering them. And this was only issuing certificates without adding them to the actual db. After I registered some users and registered them I was able to view them all in the db that is in the docker container.